# How to Split Comma Separated String and Store it in to Variables VB Net

Tags: string, vb.net

I have a comma separated string like this

```
Dim str as String = "1,5"
Dim num1, num2 As Integer
```

What I want is I want to separate the string through Comma and store these values to the new integer variables. After separation I want something like this

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 5
```

I want to do something like this.

```
 num1, num2 = Convert.ToInt32(str.Split(","))
```

this is possible in Python but I don't know how to do it here

Comment: str.Split(",")?

Comment: @J.Salas this i know than how i will store it to these variables?

Comment: @J.Salas num1, num2 = myString.split(",") something like this. this is possible in python but i don't know how to do in vb

Comment: You do it manually looping through the result of the Split. For each ...

Comment: @AndrewMortimer can you post solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string and assign into variables like this:

```
Private Sub AssignVars()

    Dim str As String = "1,5"
    Dim num1, num2 As Integer
    Dim results() As String

    results = str.Split(Convert.ToChar(","))

    For pos As Integer = 0 To results.Count - 1
        Select Case pos
            Case 0
                Integer.TryParse(results(pos), num1)
            Case 1
                Integer.TryParse(results(pos), num2)
            Case Else
                'error handle?
        End Select
    Next


End Sub
```

If you're concerned about the for-case anti-pattern

```
Private Sub AssignVars()

    Dim str As String = "1,5"
    Dim num1, num2 As Integer
    Dim results() As String

    results = str.Split(Convert.ToChar(","))

    Integer.TryParse(results(0), num1)
    Integer.TryParse(results(1), num2)

End Sub
```

Comment: For-case anti-pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
    Dim str As String = "b,1,,5,a,,6"
    Dim num1, num2 As Integer
    Dim results() As Integer

    results = (From s In str.Split(","c)
                Where Integer.TryParse(s, Nothing)
                Select Integer.Parse(s) Take 2).ToArray

    If results.Length = 2 Then
        num1 = results(0)
        num2 = results(1)
    Else
        'error
    End If
```